# What's different between the normal memory object and OpenCL's pipe?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Pipe is one of the OpenCL 2.0's new features, and this feature has been demonstrated in the AMDAPPSDK's producer/consumer example. I've read some articles abut pipe's use cases and they're all like the producer/consumer way.

My question is, the same functionality can be achieved by creating a global memory space/object and passing the pointer to 2 kernel functions given that OpenCL 2.0 provides the shared virtual memory. So what's the difference between a pipe object and a global memory object? Or is it invented just for optimization?

Answer (score 2):

It is as useful as `std::vector` and `std::queue`.
One is useful to store data, while the other is useful to store packets.

Packets are indeed data, but it is much easier to handle them as small units rather than a big block.

Pipes in OpenCL allow you to consume these small packets in a kernel, without having to deal with the indexing + storing + pointers + forloops hell that would happen if you manually implement a pipe mechanism yourself in the kernel.

Comment: So pipe is nothing more like a set of utility functions?

Answer (score 2):

Pipes are useful for example when each work item can generate variable number of outputs. Prior to OpenCL 2.0 this was difficult to handle.

Pipes may reside in faster memory (vendor specific) i.e. Altera recommends using pipes to exchange data between kernels instead of using global memory.

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are designed to transfer data from one kernel to another kernel/s without the need to store/load data in/from global or host memory. This is essentially a FIFO on the FPGA device. So, the speed of access of the data are much faster than that of through DDR or host memory. This is probably the reason to use FPGA as an accelerator.

Sometimes the DDRs are used to share data between kernels as well. One example is that a SIMD kernel want to share some data with a single task kernel with requirement on input data sequence. As, Pipes will run out of order in a SIMD way.

Other than the Pipes, you can use Altera channels for more function support. But this is not portable to other OpenCL devices.

Hope this can help. :)

Comment: I understand that your asnwer is based on FPGAs. But is there any such advantage in using pipes on the GPU side (like being able to use faster memory)? Because when i tried using pipes on GPUs the pipe seems to be using the global memory (as there is no runtime improvement). So is there any performance advantage to using pipes in scenarios where its possible to use a normal buffer (on GPUs) ?

Comment: @JohnsPaul to be honest, I'm not familiar with the GPU programming. But according to the OpenCL framework, there should be private/local memory spaces which have faster access than global. may be have a check to the GPU vendor manual, to see how the pipe is implemented? if it is only route the data to the global, then i think it is less likely to get any performance improve via pipe.

Comment: Ok. I am using an AMD A10 APU and i couldnt find any documentation which gives details about the pipe implemenetation on the A10 device I am using. I did write a few test programs to see if there are any performance improvements if we use pipes instead of a global buffer. From those the performance only gets worse due to the additional synhcronization needed for implementing pipes (like calls to reserve_pipe). Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @JohnsPaul thanks for letting us know your findings :)